# How to play Team Sonic Racing in local coop mode using single joycon

Tags: nintendo-switch, team-sonic-racing

I have been playing video games my entire life and am really embarrassed to not be able to figure this out!  Both halves of the joycon insist on syncing as P1.  I am trying to get one half P1, the other P2 (both the back of the case and online manual make it sound as though this is possible), but no matter what combination of +/- I try they both want to sync as P1.  What am I missing?

Comment: I don't have the game to check it out, but have you tried setting your joycons for two separate players in Controllers Settings (Switch settings, not the game settings) and then launching (if it's already running, close it and restart) the game? I know games that only see the changes in controller once its changed in there (e.g. Binding of Isaac). Not posting this as an answer as this is only a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use one pair of joy con controllers split between two players in Team Sonic Racing for split screen.

In order for this to work as expected you need to make sure that the Switch has detected that this is your control scheme in the main menu before you start the game and then when you select 2 player it will work with one joy con per player like Mario Kart does. To do this you need to go to the controller settings screen before starting the game, and ensure that the Switch is detecting that player one is using one half of the joy con controller and player two is using the other half.